# Is there any widely used C++ unit testing framework that supports test categories?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm currently using CppUnit for testing, but am frustrated by the lack of support for the concept of [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2). **Is there any widely used C++ unit testing framework that supports this idea?**

Here's an example straight from NUnit documentation:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [Category("LongRunning")]
  public class LongRunningTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The idea is to be able to group tests in different categories, and to execute tests in specified categories, or perhaps to exclude tests based on their category.

I have tried CppUnit, Boost.Test and Google Test, none of which directly support this idea.

*For example,* I have *unit* tests, *integration* tests, *medium* tests, and *large* tests. *unit* and *integration* tests run quickly, so I run them in every build configuration in the automated build: Release/Debug, x86/x64, linux/windows. *medium* tests take time to run, so I only run them in *Release|x64|windows* build. *large* tests exist as development aids: they are never run in the automated build. Then to add to the fun, I have features that only exist in x86|windows (it's complicated). I do all this with a complicated hierarchy, which CppUnit happily supports. However, it would be much nicer to do this with categories such as "release", "debug", "x86", etc.

In CppUnit, my tests are currently in Fixture classes. Ideally, I'd like to be able to tag those Fixtures with Categories, which I could then filter accordingly.

The one key thing that a test hierarchy *doesn't* do, which categories *would* do, is to have multiple categories on a single fixture.

Comment: In CppUnit, I used sub-tests to represent categories.  However, there is no category attribute or property associated with a test item.

Comment: You can use macro wrappers like `#define UnitTest` and `#define IntegrationTest` around e.g. Boost.Test or gtest and pass these macro symbols to the command line of your compiler in order to select between different categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [--run_test option in **Boost.Test**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html) supports wildcard matching for the test and or suite names. I'm not entirely sure how flexible the matching is, but if you were to put tag-like naming part into your test(-suite) names, you could perhaps run `--run_test=suite_LongRunning*/*` something like that.

---

I also just stumbled on [**xUnit++**](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit/wiki/Compare.wiki) which has [Attributes](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit/wiki/SuitesAndAttributes.wiki) that can be used to [run](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit/wiki/RunningTests.wiki) different categories. (Since it's modeled after NUnit, this should be no wonder.)

Comment: xUnit++ Attributes does seem to be the answer to my question thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain I understand the question. Allow me to write some pseudo-code to see if I understand:

```
class TestCategory : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestCase {

    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_BEGIN(TestCategory);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(myTestFunction);
    CPPUNITT_TEST_SUITE_END();

protected:

    void myTestFunction() {}

}
```

You can have *n* number of these classes. In the main:

```
// headers omitted

CPPUNT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(TestCategory)
// more registrations here
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(TestCategory_n_)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   // test runner steps
}
```

Forgive me for being obtuse, but you're looking for a logical partition in the testing architecture, yes? If so, you can group your tests via classes and include them as necessary in the main function.

Help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, yup, your answer is one way to do it, and that would work. I added some info about what I currently do in the OP. Essentially I'd just like a bit more flexibility than I've got right now, if I can get it.

Comment: @Boinst I understand now. CppUnit doesn't support such a notion AFAIK, it looks like you'll have to update your test hierarchy to make the "categories" work. I'd have one, top-level makefile with several targets in it such as "big-test", "small-test", "unit-test", etc. That way you could compile and run as needed. Also, look into a continuous integration server, like `Hudson` to perform this task for you.