# Select which C++ unit tests to run based on attribute tags or categories?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tags, categories, googletest

We have a large number of tests/platforms/environments/configurations, and want certain C++ unit tests to run on only some of them.

We already have a similar system using Citrus integration tests, where we use around ~50 tags to identify environments and/or properties, where a specific test shall not run (exclusive tags); a few tags specify properties which imply the test is limited to a specific environment/configuration (inclusive tags).

Because of the many tags already in use, and new tags bound to come, filtering which test cases to execute based on test name (like GTest supports using --gtest_filter) is therefore **not** feasible.

Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698999/is-there-any-widely-used-c-unit-testing-framework-that-supports-test-categorie), I see that [xUnit++](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit/wiki/SuitesAndAttributes.wiki) supports this; but only for 8 different tags. Also, this project was last updated 2015, which is not attractive to us (we need a solution for a commercial product).

Does anyone know a framework which supports our requirements, or has an idea how to simply extend one of the well established ones, like GTest?

Comment: ******bump******